# How to properly use Aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use the aliases OriginalCost and QuantityDiscount to do some calculation. I understand that you can only use aliases in GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY, but I have not sure about how to do it the right way. The error I am getting with this code is

> Line 9
>   Invalid column name 'QuantityDiscount'.

```
SELECT  Orders.Orderid, Inventory.partid, Description, Qty, (Inventory.price) AS UnitPrice, 
        (OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.price) AS OriginalCost, 
        CASE 
            WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 5 THEN (OriginalCost) * .05)
            WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 10 THEN (OriginalCost) * .10)
            ELSE 0
        END AS QuantityDiscount,
        SUM(OriginalCost  - QuantityDiscount) AS FinalCost
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderItems ON OrderItems.orderid = OrderItems.orderid
JOIN Inventory ON ORDERITEMS.partid = Inventory.partid
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

Comment: I'm rolling back your edit. Your original question was about the aliases, and that has been answered here. You should post a separate question now about the GROUP BY. Once you've gotten answers, you can't change the entire question being asked; it voids all of the answers you've received already, and tends to get them downvoted because they no longer apply to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any sample data, so this is untested:

```
SELECT 
  t.OrderID,
  t.PartID,
  t.Description,
  t.Qty,
  t.UnitPrice,
  t.OriginalCost,
  t.QuantityDiscount,
  SUM(t.OriginalCost - t.QuantityDiscount) AS FinalCost
FROM (
    SELECT  
      Orders.Orderid, 
      Inventory.partid, 
      Description, 
      Qty, 
      (Inventory.price) AS UnitPrice, 
      (OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.price) AS OriginalCost, 
      CASE 
        WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 5 THEN (OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.Price) * .05)
        WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 10 THEN (OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.Price) * .10)
        ELSE 0
      END AS QuantityDiscount
    FROM 
      Orders
    JOIN 
      OrderItems ON OrderItems.orderid = OrderItems.orderid
    JOIN 
      Inventory ON ORDERITEMS.partid = Inventory.partid
) AS t
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can define aliases the following ways:

```
SELECT Alias = TableAlias.Field         --prefixed to a field
       ,TableAlias.Field as OtherAlias  --at the end of a field
FROM Table TableAlias                   --on a table
--then use by anything that is caculated after that part in the order of operations.
ORDER BY Alias;
```

Then you can use them after the area they are defined in.

SQL Order of Operations:

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use alias defined in the same select statement. You will have to use sub-queries or table expression.

Something like this (code not tested but just to give you the idea)

```
SELECT * 
        ,SUM(t2.OriginalCost - t2.QuantityDiscount) AS FinalCost
FROM
  ( SELECT * 
           ,CASE WHEN t1.Qty >= 5 THEN (t1.OriginalCost * .05) WHEN t1.Qty >= 10 THEN (t1.OriginalCost * .10) ELSE 0 END AS QuantityDiscount
    FROM
          ( SELECT Orders.Orderid,
                   Inventory.partid,
                   Description,
                   Qty,
                   (Inventory.price) AS UnitPrice,
                   (OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.price) AS OriginalCost
           FROM Orders
           JOIN OrderItems ON OrderItems.orderid = OrderItems.orderid
           JOIN Inventory ON ORDERITEMS.partid = Inventory.partid 
           ) AS t1 

  ) AS t2
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
  Orderid,
  partid,
  Description,
  Qty,
  UnitPrice,
  OriginalCost,
  QuantityDiscount,
  OriginalCost  - QuantityDiscount AS FinalCost
FROM (
  SELECT  
    Orders.Orderid, Inventory.partid, Description, Qty, 
    Inventory.price AS UnitPrice, 
    (OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.price) AS OriginalCost, 
    CASE 
       WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 5 THEN (OriginalCost) * .05)
       WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 10 THEN (OriginalCost) * .10)
       ELSE 0
    END AS QuantityDiscount
  FROM Orders
) T
JOIN OrderItems ON OrderItems.orderid = OrderItems.orderid
JOIN Inventory ON ORDERITEMS.partid = Inventory.partid
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

If you still need amy aggregations at this point, wrap another query around this one as a sub-query.